# Finding the necessary details to add a network printer(DNSSD) in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, network-printer

I'm a Linux user who is rather ignorant about Windows. We have a printer at work that is connected directly to the network. It has its own IP address and isn't configured as a printer share on some particular computer. It's a standalone printer.

All our Linux machines can find this printer automatically and connect to it via DNSSD. Now, I'm trying to configure my co-worker's Windows 7 laptop to use the printer, and I'm having trouble.

First, Windows can't seem to find it on the network, even though the Linux machines have no trouble. So, I tried manually add it by IP address. But Windows wants the port name. I know what a port *number* is, but I've never heard of a port *name*. At any rate, I don't know what port number the printer is listening on, because my Linux machines hide all that detail behind a single `dnssd://` URL that Windows doesn't understand.

How can I set up the printer? (By the way, the printer has no English documentation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With most network printers, adding a "Local TCP/IP-Port" is most easy (that's the port name stuff you wrote of, it's not a TCP port, but a virtual printer port). This is usually the preferred way to connect to a network printer as it does not require any software but the drivers.

Though some names have changed from XP to 7, you should be able to follow [this tutorial](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-xp/how-to-install-a-network-printer-on-your-home-or-office-network/).

If you want to use DNSSD, maybe Apple's Bonjour could help you, it contains some assistant to add a bonjour printer.

Comment: I haven't tried Bonjour yet as I'd prefer not to install too much additional software. The method in the tutorial you linked to didn't work. Worse, even though there are many possible things that could go wrong, Windows doesn't provide any information as to what the problem is. How can I identify what's wrong?

Comment: I used Bonjour and that worked. Why the other methods of connecting didn't work remains a mystery, but I don't care anymore, as my co-worker can now print and I've spent way too much time on what should have been an easy problem. I'm going back to the Linux world of printing that Just Works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

DNSSD isn't going to work with the Local TCP/IP port.

For DNSSD, you'll need to download the Bonjour Printing Services for Windows.

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL999

Comment: I should note that any connection method is fine with me, whether DNSSD or something else. However, as I've mentioned above, I installed Bonjour as a result of Jens Erat's post, so everything is working now.

Comment: BTW, I just noticed this in your question. The port name in the case of a TCP/IP is the IP address of the printer. Or if it is registered with the DNS server, a URL will do also.

Comment: You mean that both fields have the same contents? Strange. But then again, I never pretended to understand Windows.

Comment: Well, you **don't have** to name it that way.  It's my suggestion and it's a pretty common standard from TC/IP printer ports, so others can tell what it is.  You could name it Dog for all Windows cares about.

Comment: Ah, it wasn't at all clear from me from the interface that the port name was something I could choose. I had thought that it was some network detail, since that's usually what the word port means. I understand now. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: That part of the interface is not well explored, so the confusion is understandable.